# Print md5sum of results of a find command in Linux

Tags: linux, find, md5sum

I am tryng to do checksum on all .jar files I can find in directory and its sub directories. Then print the filename with the checksum value to a file.

this is what I have.

```
md5sum | find -name *.jar >result.txt
```

I am trying to join two commands together that I know work individually.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You might also find hashdeep useful: http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use something like this to execute a command on each file:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec md5sum {} \; >result
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It worked perfect. Any addition, any way to only write the file name in the file and not the full folder path.

Comment: @JamesMclaren yes if you add `-printf "%f\n"` it will print just the filename but I don't think it will work as `md5sum` needs the full path, you could remove the path after executing the command with `sed` or `awk`

Answer (score 3):

This will also work to recursively hash all files in the current directory or sub-directories (thanks to my sysadmin!):

```
md5sum $(find . -name '*.jar') > result.txt
```

The above will prepend "./" to the filename (without including the path).

Using the `-exec` suggestion from mux prepends "*" to the filename (again, without the path).

The listed file order also differed between the two, but I am unqualified to say exactly why, since I'm a complete noob to bash scripting.

Edit:  Forget the above regarding the prepend and full path, which was based on my experience running remotely on an HPC.  I just ran my sysadmin's suggestion on my local Windows box using cygwin and got the full path, with "*./" prepended.  I'll need to use some other fanciness to dump the inconsistent path and prepending, to make the comparison easier.  In short, YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

You can also pipe the results to `xargs`:

```
find . -name "*.jar" | xargs md5sum > result.txt
```